# exam components free?

Tags: php, mysql

i need to implement a on-line exam using php and mysql, so need to get your opinion about good exam modules that are written using php? if it is free and easily configurable that is good! i need to easily modify the code and reconfigure it and include it with my own questions! i think you guys can give me better suggestions in this matter?? please suggest me what to do??

regards,
Rangana

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a look into an online survey tool and extend that for your needs. Survey usually have radiobutton, checkbox and textfield answers, which is all you need in an exam as well.